# Can Space-time be manipulated by a highly technologically advanced civilization?

Tags: internal-consistency, gravity, energy

I would like to build on a previous question and queries of my own on the possibilities of manipulating the form of space-time for a space opera i am working on.

If we can go on the theory that matter is a form of energy and space itself is just another form of the same thing, virtual particles could be used as an example that it is a fluctuating energy field or a scalar field filled with the radiation energy from every cosmic process that previously occurred.

So if space-time is a scaler field of known quantum properties does it still follow the same rules if it can condensed into a structure that an advanced civilization could manipulate for their own imaginative weapons or defence structures? would gravity still be the dominant force and the properties of neutron stars as their way to control this condensed form or if the condensed form is taken further could a blackhole-like collapse of matter and space be formed in a band and not a singular point, although that seems like an inevitable end to a theory of a condensed maximum space-time construct?

Answer (score 2):

**Looks good enough for space opera.**

"If the condensed form is taken further could a blackhole-like collapse of matter and space be formed in a band and not a singular point, although that seems like an inevitable end to a theory of a condensed maximum space-time construct?"

"If you say so, Doc.  Now hold the tiller while I get my raygun!"

Good doubletalk you got there Roger, but you could lean into it a little more.  Gobbledygook!   No-one understands Doc when he gets going (except his twin, who is a head in a jar now). No-one likes his personal habits either (including his twin, because those habits are the reason he is now a head in a jar).  But people like very much how Doc can Make Ship Go when that is needed, and so he earns his keep.

Comment: "If the condensed form is taken further could a blackhole-like collapse of matter and space be formed in a band and not a singular point" dunno, but they can be a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_singularity)